# Background process on webserver with an ASMX Webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, asmx

I am facing an issue, i need to recieve user request through an asmx webservice and for each request i need to:

1) Send back to the user an Id for his request. Something like: "Your request has been received with id ####". (The id is generated by the DB, an autoincrement column.)

2) Start a background process without blocking the user for response, i mean the webservice sends back the Id and starts the process in background.

I understand that maybe i should use WCF but i think the server cant run it, but if you could talk me about the answer of this in both of them kind of services, much better.

I have no idea about doing this task. I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Maybe check out something like Quartz.NET?  http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: If the server is running .NET 3.0 or above, then it can run WCF.

Comment: The process i need to do is not complex, just go to request about financial information about the user, but i need the bg process because the financial service could not response inmediatly. I am recording into a database the "process" i have to do, What About if in the application_start (Global.asax) just launch a backgroundworker with a thread.sleep for timing, looking for records to be processed into the database and for each "process" found launch another backgroundworker?

Answer (score 1):

Usually I do this with the help of a scheduled task that starts a console application at regular intervals.

The communication between the ASMX web service and the scheduled console application is done through the database where I fill a work item queue table.

With this (maybe not *that* elegant aproach) I get the following benefits:

- Bypass the background threading in ASP.NET altogether (which I honestly do not fully understand)
- Make the background processing even work correctly if the ASP.NET application is being restarted.

Depending on the requirements the scheduled task can run as often as needed, e.g. every 5 minutes or just once a day.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I cant use console application because the webserver is a webhosting and they does not allow me to install apps, just i can put into the IIS. The process i need to do is not complex, just go to request about financial information about the user, but i need the bg process because the financial service could not response inmediatly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use MSMQ.  Create a queue to handle the incoming requests and a service to take tasks from the queue and process them.  It'a hard to suggest the 'right' solution without knowing more about your specifics.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Is MSMQ enabled in typical web hosting?. The process i need to do is not complex, just go to request about financial information about the user, but i need the bg process because the financial service could not response inmediatly.

Comment: Yes it is, the company just buy the service of web hosting.

Answer (score 0):

I would just run a background task (maybe in your global.asax) that works out of a queue of logged requests, picks them up and actually does them.

Your .asmx method would then just be adding to this queue (including the ID), thus can immediately return to the user while the task is being processed in the background...